# CMakeList to compile and link an executable using Boost

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm beginner with CMake and C++ compilation but it's seems that unlike Java I need to be very explicit with my CMakeList.txt in order to link src with correct header and libraries in my project.

Here is my CMakeList.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4)
project(AwesomeScheduler)

include_directories(header)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++14")
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/../bin)

find_package(Boost COMPONENTS system filesystem REQUIRED)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

set(SOCKET_SOUCE_FILES
        src/socket.cpp
        header/socket.h)

set(DISPTACHER_SOURCE_FILES
        src/dispatcher.cpp
        header/dispatcher.h
        header/util.h)

set(ENDUSER_SOURCE_FILES
        src/end-user.cpp
        header/end-user.h
        header/util.h)

set(TASKPROPERTIES_SOURCE_FILES
        src/task_properties.cpp
        header/task_properties.h)

add_executable(Dispatcher ${SOCKET_SOUCE_FILES} ${DISPTACHER_SOURCE_FILES})

add_executable(EndUser ${SOCKET_SOUCE_FILES} ${ENDUSER_SOURCE_FILES} ${TASKPROPERTIES_SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(EndUser ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

The compilation works well and I get my two executables but I wonder if there is a way less verbose to get the same result?

Comment: ***I wonder if there is a way less verbose to get the same result?*** In my opinion not really. There is globbing which can save you from typing a few file names but I would not bother. When you get to larger projects (I have ones with 1000s of source files) you may use functions and macros in CMake however for a simple example like this it would not help.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am now wondering why g ++ is not able to automatically link headers files that are specified in the "cpp" sources ?

Comment: You do not need to specify the headers if you do not plan to use an IDE for your project. I primarily use Visual Studio for my projects and if I do not specify the headers they do not show up in the solution view (making it harder to navigate in the ide) however the code will build fine.

Comment: honestly it's a pretty good looking, readable cmake file.

Comment: I agree. What you have is about right, not too simple, not too complex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As commented by @drescherjm and @NicolasHolthaus your example code already looks pretty good. If you are getting less verbose, you will always loose some information.

**Minimal Version**

To demonstrate this, let's take a look at a minimal version of your code:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4)
project(AwesomeScheduler)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/bin")

find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system filesystem)

include_directories(header)

add_executable(Dispatcher src/socket.cpp src/dispatcher.cpp)
add_executable(EndUser src/socket.cpp src/end-user.cpp src/task_properties.cpp)
target_link_libraries(EndUser Boost::system Boost::filesystem)
```

I have

- moved the source files into the `add_executable()` calls
- eliminated the header files
- used the `IMPORTED` targets from Boost, which implicitly declares the header paths also
- done some cosmetic changes to the global settings

  - used the more cross-platform [`CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD.html) setting
  - using `..` from the binary dir looks odd, I assumed something relative to the source dir

**Something in Between**

Because grouping the source files and adding the header files has its advantages in respect of readability, maintainability and CMake's own abilities during build environment generation, here is what I would have done in the setup you have described here:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4)
project(AwesomeScheduler)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/bin")

find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system filesystem)

set(
    SOCKET_SOUCE_FILES
        src/socket.cpp
        header/socket.h
)
set(
    ENDUSER_SOURCE_FILES
        src/end-user.cpp
        header/end-user.h
        src/task_properties.cpp
        header/task_properties.h
        header/util.h
)
set(
    DISPTACHER_SOURCE_FILES
        src/dispatcher.cpp
        header/dispatcher.h
        header/util.h
)

add_library(Socket OBJECT ${SOCKET_SOUCE_FILES})
target_include_directories(Socket PUBLIC header)

add_executable(Dispatcher ${DISPTACHER_SOURCE_FILES} $<TARGET_OBJECTS:Socket>)
target_include_directories(Dispatcher PRIVATE header)

add_executable(EndUser ${ENDUSER_SOURCE_FILES} $<TARGET_OBJECTS:Socket>)
target_include_directories(Dispatcher PRIVATE header)
target_link_libraries(EndUser Boost::system Boost::filesystem)
```

Now you have

- the possibility to

  - add/remove files conditionally to your source file lists
  - reuse the lists in calls to e.g. [`set_source_files_properties()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set_source_files_properties.html) or [`source_group()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/source_group.html)
- the headers getting checked for availability and added to IDE projects during generation
- the grouping of Socket sources into a [object library](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html#object-libraries) with e.g. it's own set of target properties to be modified
- no global include directory anymore, but target specific include directories

  - on this small project with only one `header` folder it might be oversized, but if your code gets larger you should definitely think about the directory structure of your code
  - So it could look something like

    ```
    AwesomeScheduler/
      CMakeLists.txt
      Dispatcher/
        CMakeLists.txt
        src/
          dispatcher.cpp
          dispatcher.h
      EndUser/
        CMakeLists.txt
        src/
          end-user.cpp
          end-user.h
      lib/
        Socket/
          CMakeLists.txt
          src/
            socket.cpp
          include/
            socket.h
      include/
        util.h
    ```

**References**

- [FindBoost CMake Module](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindBoost.html)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6594796/how-do-i-make-cmake-output-into-a-bin-dir
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851247/how-to-activate-c-11-in-cmake
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2924037/separate-include-and-src-folders-for-application-level-code
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2360734/whats-a-good-directory-structure-for-larger-c-projects-using-makefile
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36872117/various-libs-in-subfolders-how-do-i-export-them-to-the-parent